# Error starting JBOSS 7.4 after upgrade javamelody version from 1.65.0 to 1.66.0

Tags: spring, jboss, java-11, java-melody

I'm upgrading the project dependencies and I'm getting this error after upgrade javamelody-core version from 1.65 to 1.66. The error occurs when I try start JBOSS server.

```
10:22:20,187 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."coecontextTest.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."coecontextTest.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Falha ao processar a fase POST_MODULE de deployment "coecontextTest.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl: when selecting method org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorFactory.usingContext()Lorg/hibernate/validator/HibernateValidatorContext; the class loader 'org.hibernate.validator@6.0.22.Final-redhat-00002' @554864d (instance of org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader, child of 'app' jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader) for super interface org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorFactory, and the class loader 'deployment.coecontextTest.war' @13bc62ff (instance of org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader, child of 'app' jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader) of the selected method's type, org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl have different Class objects for the type org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidatorContext used in the signature
    at deployment.coecontextTest.war//org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at deployment.coecontextTest.war//org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi@6.0.22.Final-redhat-00002//org.hibernate.validator.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@7.4.2.GA-redhat-00002//org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@7.4.2.GA-redhat-00002//org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@7.4.2.GA-redhat-00002//org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
```

I have checked the subdependencies and not catch the problem. Any Idea?

[My pom file for download](https://file.io/WWS9qnZTrg78)

Comment: It was a cache bug.  I have clear all possible caches of my Eclipse IDE and JBOSS. Now this error doesn't occurs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/634

I suggest to try the upgrade to javamelody 1.68.0 or to javamelody 1.92.0